# how to load remote file into db2 database using jdbc

Tags: jdbc, db2, load, db2-luw

i'm trying to load from a local file into a db2 database using jdbc. the code looks like below:

```
stmt = jdbc.connection.prepareCall("call sysproc.db2load(....)")
stmt.regParameter(3, "load client from D:\\a.del of del insert into a")
```

but it doesn't work. The "SYSPROC.DB2LOAD" option is incompatible with the "CLIENT" option

so is there any way i can use jdbc to load local file into db2??

Comment: Which operating-system runs the Db2-server (where the database lives) , is it Z/OS,  i- series  or  Linux/Unix/Windows ?

Comment: linux centos, v9.1

Comment: Do you really mean Db2 v9.1?   That is an antique.  It does support the `ADMIN_CMD` stored procedure, which itself allows the `LOAD` but __only__ after you have scp'd the file from workstation to a location accessible to the Db2-server and readable by the Db2-instance-owner.  Alternative is to not use java and jdbc to do the load, but instead to run a script at the workstation that uses local `db2` client and performs the `db2 load client from d:\a.del insert into ...`  (the file can then reside on the client).

Comment: tks, it seems db2 load doesn't support local file well. 
i'll ftp/scp the file to the server and call the proc again.

Comment: The Db2-Linux-Unix-Windows `LOAD` and `LOAD CLIENT` are both commands, they are not any part of SQL . Only `LOAD CLIENT' allows the file to be local to the Db2-client (i.e. not on the server). jdbc is focussed on SQL and DDL. jdbc does not cater for external commands (such as load or load client). But by using stored-procedures, you circumvent this __as long as__ the file to be loaded is accessible (readable) to the Db2-instance owner on the Db2-server.